# How to redirect to locally stored index.html file when localhost:<port> is called from a browser

Tags: java, android, server, localhost, serversocket

I am creating a socket server in android. I have a directory in my local storage in which there is index.html and all other resources needed. I want that when i start the socket server and then call localhost: from my mobile's browser then it redirects to the index.html.
My socket is running. the logs are printing. the issue is i don't know how to redirect to index.html. 
Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
public class Server {
MainActivity activity;
ServerSocket serverSocket;
String message = "";
static final int socketServerPORT = 8080;

public Server(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
    socketServerThread.start();
}

public int getPort() {
    return socketServerPORT;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (serverSocket != null) {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // create ServerSocket using specified port
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

            while (true) {
                // block the call until connection is created and return
                // Socket object
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                count++;
                message += "#" + count + " from "
                        + socket.getInetAddress() + ":"
                        + socket.getPort() + "\n";

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("SocketServerThread.run i am running");
                    }
                });

                SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread =
                        new SocketServerReplyThread(socket, count);
                socketServerReplyThread.run();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

    private Socket hostThreadSocket;
    int cnt;

    SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
        hostThreadSocket = socket;
        cnt = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        OutputStream outputStream;

        String msgReply = "Hello from Server, you are #" + cnt;
          final String OUTPUT = "https://www.google.com";
          final String OUTPUT_HEADERS = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n" +
                  "date: Fri, 25 Oct 2019 04:58:29 GMT"+
                "Content-Length: ";
             final String OUTPUT_END_OF_HEADERS = "\r\n\r\n";
        try {
            outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(
                            new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream),"UTF-8" ));

                    out.write(OUTPUT_HEADERS + OUTPUT.length() + OUTPUT_END_OF_HEADERS + OUTPUT);

            out.flush();
            out.close();

            return;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Here is another message for you " + message);
            }
        });
    }
}

public String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress
                        .nextElement();

                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip += "Server running at : "
                            + inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
    }
    return ip;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the browser receiving now?

Comment: Do you wanna make your own webserver?

Comment: @blackapps currently it just prints htps://www.google.com

Comment: yes kind of own webserver. @blackapps

Comment: What sense makes that? And why dont you let it print the contents of index.html? Read the contents of the file then write it to the output stream.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution to my problem here it is

```
   static final File WEB_ROOT = new File("<your files path>");
static final String DEFAULT_FILE = "index.html";
static final String FILE_NOT_FOUND = "404.html";
static final String METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED = "not_supported.html";

  private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // create ServerSocket using specified port
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);
                while (true) {
                // block the call until connection is created and return
                // Socket object
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                connect = socket;
                count++;
                message += "#" + count + " from "
                        + socket.getInetAddress() + ":"
                        + socket.getPort() + "\n";

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("SocketServerThread.run i am running");
                    }
                });

                JavaHTTPServer.SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread =
                        new JavaHTTPServer.SocketServerReplyThread(socket, count);
                socketServerReplyThread.run();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

    private Socket hostThreadSocket;
    int cnt;

    SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
        hostThreadSocket = socket;
        cnt = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {// we manage our particular client connection
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedOutputStream dataOut = null;
        String fileRequested = null;

        try {
            // we read characters from the client via input stream on the socket
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            // we get character output stream to client (for headers)
            out = new PrintWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            // get binary output stream to client (for requested data)
            dataOut = new BufferedOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());

            // get first line of the request from the client
            String input = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("SocketServerReplyThread.run input " + input);
            // we parse the request with a string tokenizer
            if (input == null)
                return;
            StringTokenizer parse = new StringTokenizer(input);
            System.out.println("SocketServerReplyThread.run parse " + parse);
            String method = parse.nextToken().toUpperCase(); // we get the HTTP method of the client
            System.out.println("SocketServerReplyThread.run method " + method);
            // we get file requested
            fileRequested = parse.nextToken().toLowerCase();
            if (fileRequested.contains("?"))
                fileRequested = fileRequested.split("\\?")[0];

            System.out.println("SocketServerReplyThread.run fileRequested " + fileRequested);
            // we support only GET and HEAD methods, we check
            if (!method.equals("GET") && !method.equals("HEAD")) {
                if (verbose) {
                    System.out.println("501 Not Implemented : " + method + " method.");
                }

                // we return the not supported file to the client
                File file = new File(WEB_ROOT, METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                int fileLength = (int) file.length();
                String contentMimeType = "text/html";
                //read content to return to client
                byte[] fileData = readFileData(file, fileLength);

                // we send HTTP Headers with data to client
                out.println("HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented");
                out.println("Server: Java HTTP Server from SSaurel : 1.0");
                out.println("Date: " + new Date());
                out.println("Content-type: " + contentMimeType);
                out.println("Content-length: " + fileLength);
                out.println(); // blank line between headers and content, very important !
                out.flush(); // flush character output stream buffer
                // file
                dataOut.write(fileData, 0, fileLength);
                dataOut.flush();

            } else {
                // GET or HEAD method
                if (fileRequested.endsWith("/")) {
                    fileRequested += DEFAULT_FILE;
                }

                File file = new File(WEB_ROOT, fileRequested);
                int fileLength = (int) file.length();
                String content = getContentType(fileRequested);

                if (method.equals("GET")) { // GET method so we return content
                    byte[] fileData = readFileData(file, fileLength);

                    // send HTTP Headers
                    out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    out.println("Server: Java HTTP Server from SSaurel : 1.0");
                    out.println("Date: " + new Date());
                    out.println("Content-type: " + content);
                    out.println("Content-length: " + fileLength);
                    out.println(); // blank line between headers and content, very important !
                    out.flush(); // flush character output stream buffer

                    dataOut.write(fileData, 0, fileLength);
                    dataOut.flush();
                }

                if (verbose) {
                    System.out.println("File " + fileRequested + " of type " + content + " returned");
                }

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            try {
                fileNotFound(out, dataOut, fileRequested);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Error with file not found exception : " + ioe.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Server error : " + ioe);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                dataOut.close();
                connect.close(); // we close socket connection
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error closing stream : " + e.getMessage());
            }

            if (verbose) {
                System.out.println("Connection closed.\n");
            }
        }

    }
}


private byte[] readFileData(File file, int fileLength) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    byte[] fileData = new byte[fileLength];

    try {
        fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileIn.read(fileData);
    } finally {
        if (fileIn != null)
            fileIn.close();
    }

    return fileData;
}

// return supported MIME Types
private String getContentType(String fileRequested) {
    if (fileRequested.endsWith(".htm") || fileRequested.endsWith(".html"))
        return "text/html";
    else
        return "text/plain";
}

private void fileNotFound(PrintWriter out, OutputStream dataOut, String fileRequested) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(WEB_ROOT, FILE_NOT_FOUND);
    int fileLength = (int) file.length();
    String content = "text/html";
    byte[] fileData = readFileData(file, fileLength);

    out.println("HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found");
    out.println("Server: Java HTTP Server from SSaurel : 1.0");
    out.println("Date: " + new Date());
    out.println("Content-type: " + content);
    out.println("Content-length: " + fileLength);
    out.println(); // blank line between headers and content, very important !
    out.flush(); // flush character output stream buffer

    dataOut.write(fileData, 0, fileLength);
    dataOut.flush();

    if (verbose) {
        System.out.println("File " + fileRequested + " not found");
    }
}
```